# JavascriptInterface annotation for JELLY_BEAN and below

Tags: java, android

As clearly noted on [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29), usage of @JavascriptInterface is needed for API level JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above, to access a java function from the webview side.

This means that Project Build Target must point to API 17 or above which resolves the following import:

```
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
```

How does android handles this code for API 16 and below? Will I get a runtime exception or does it ignore this import on runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite surprised with these answers... they are not accurate. 
If you add the JavascriptInterface and another annotation lets say **MyAnnotation** to the same method(like I did), and then try to access the **MyAnnotation** instance annotation then you are in for a ClassDefNotFoundException surprise!

My solution which seems to work for now (it has been more than a year), is to add the annotation declaration to the application project:

```
package android.webkit;


import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface JavascriptInterface {}
```

This solved the problem on 2.3.5, and still worked on 4.3 and 4.4 and 4.2.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: How do you apply your answer? create {{project}}/JavascriptInterface.java and put the above code in it and import {{which_file}}?

Comment: you add a {Project}/src/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.java and you import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

Answer (score 4):

The annotation class JavascriptInterface is not loaded by older Android versions, so your code will run without any issue on older versions.

Comment: Well, if this annotation is loaded by older Android versions, how could this annotation protect against CVE-2012-6636?

Comment: @peacepassion Android versions 16 or lower are vulnerable. See http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-6636. All I said earlier is that if a developer uses the annotation JavascriptInterface, it will crash at runtime when running on older Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

Imports like the one you have suggested `import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;` are only hints to the compiler so it can resolve the full class path you are referring to further on in your source. The VM will only throw a `ClassNotFoundException` when you try and use the class. So the simple answer is no, everything will be fine as long as you protect your use of the `JavascriptInterface` with something like the following.

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
        JavascriptInterface js = new JavascriptInterface(){ ... };
    }
```