# Webview does not working as expected on and above KITKAT

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm trying to execute javascript in webview in my app. It works perfectly below kitkat but when testing app on the kitkat and above devices app behaves strange.
It does not find the method. Here's my code snippet of Javascript

```
function callTojavaFn(verse) {
    var msg = "Calling from Java Script";
    JsHandler.forwardSelectedVerses(verse);
}
```

And here's my android snippet

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
                CookieManager cookies = CookieManager.getInstance();
                cookies.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(wvVerses, true);
            }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        webView.evaluateJavascript(webUrl,new ValueCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
               Log.d("javascript:getSelectedVerse",value);
          }
   });
```

**Here's my log Log of after KitKat**

[image: Log of after KitKat]

**This one is before kitkat**

[image: before kitkat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to my limited experience with webView; from the snipped of your code I cannot tell exactly what issues your code have, but I have some ideas on what MIGHT be happening.

I think your issues come from changes in API, if you want your app to work on target sdk version 17 and up add **@JavascriptInterface** right before the public method(or class) which you want to make available for webview (and which your compiler couldn't find on kitkat). You may find an example on the following link in Binding JavaScript code to Android code section: [android webview guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html). This will run your code on newer versions, but you will get errors for earlier versions. If you want your app work for older and newer target sdk I would look into "Simon" answer on the following question: [JavascriptInterface annotation for JELLY_BEAN and below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380368/javascriptinterface-annotation-for-jelly-bean-and-below)

If my previous suggestion doesn't work I would recommend either to post more code or to look into tutorial about changes in new version of Webview(starting from 19-kitkat) on the following link: [migrating to target sdk 19 and higher](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html). It describes the issues you might encounter in newer webView and how to fix them.

Comment: Thanks a lot this thing works for me. I've tried each and every solution available this thing works
Because of one of the solution link on developer.gogole.com.
in specific i add annotation @JavascriptInterface before metod tat access from javascript.
Thanks once again

Comment: No in one shot your solution does work as expected. Thanks